# conditional file search and removal

Tags: command-line, delete

I have some items that have 15 images and some that have less than 15 images associated with their IDs. How can I only keep the ones that have 15 images with them?

```
$ ls -l 72065050* | wc -l
15
$ ls -l 71088714* | wc -l
3
```

and

```
$ ls 71088714*
71088714_0.jpg  71088714_1.jpg  71088714_2.jpg
$ ls 72065050*
72065050_0.jpg   72065050_11.jpg  72065050_13.jpg  72065050_1.jpg  72065050_3.jpg  72065050_5.jpg  72065050_7.jpg  72065050_9.jpg
72065050_10.jpg  72065050_12.jpg  72065050_14.jpg  72065050_2.jpg  72065050_4.jpg  72065050_6.jpg  72065050_8.jpg
```

Additionally, how can I figure how many of these IDs have 15 images associated with them?

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but you can do something like:

```
printf "%s\n" *.jpg | cut -d_ -f1 | sort -u | while IFS= read -r prefix; do
    files=( "$prefix"*.jpg )
    if [[ "${#files[@]}" -ne 15 ]]; then
        echo rm "$prefix"*
    fi
done
```

That finds the list of unique prefixes and, for each one, put the list of files into an array: if the size of the array is not 15 then remove.

Comment: You mean „if the size of the array is *not* 15 then remove.“, don't you? You should mention that `echo` needs to be removed after testing, this may not be obvious to everybody.

Comment: this also didn't remove the files. It just echoes that it is removing files.

Comment: @Mona presumably that's so that you can safely test the script without removing your files, you just remove the `echo` once you have tested the script and seen that it works

Comment: @glenn running your script, I get `rm: cannot remove ‘71088714*’: No such file or directory` and `$ ls 71088714*
71088714_0.jpg  71088714_1.jpg  71088714_2.jpg` I get that for all the files it tries to remove. What is the matter?

Comment: @MonaJalal the `*` there should have been outside the quotes, I fixed that now. @ glen - maybe you can use `uniq -c` and get the counting done for free? Right now you're globbing thrice - once for printf, once for counting, once for deleting. At least one of those could be eliminated

Comment: @muru great idea. You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.jpg' |\
while IFS='' read -r bla; do
  if ! ls "${bla:0:7}"_14.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo rm "${bla:0:7}"*
  fi
done
```

Comment: Instead of relying on `ls`, you can ask the shell to see if that file exists: `if [[ ! -f "${bla:0:7}_14.jpg" ]]; then ...`

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1` equals `&>/dev/null`in modern `bash`.

Comment: You should mention that `echo` needs to be removed after testing to perform the removals.

Comment: hey I just realized it is not removing the files and is only echoing that is removing but it is not. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is:

```
$ declare -A pref ; for f in *_[0-9]*.jpg ; do p=${f%_*} ; (( pref[$p]++ )); done ; for p in "${!pref[@]}" ; do (( ${pref[$p]} < 15 )) &&  rm "$p"_* ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a non-shell language for this task:

```
ruby -e '
  files = Dir.glob("*")
  groups = files.group_by {|f| f.sub(/_.*/, "")}
  groups.each_value {|flist| File.delete(*flist) if flist.length < 15}
'
```

or

```
perl -e '
    foreach $f (glob "*") {
        ($prefix = $f) =~ s/_.*//;
        push @{$groups{$prefix}}, $f;
    }
    foreach $flist (values %groups) {
        unlink @$flist if (scalar @$flist < 15);
    }
'
```